# Android, navbar

Tags: android

Всем привет, я новичок в мобильной разработке,
мне надо сделать navbar для всех активностей, то есть чтобы я в каждой активности не прописывал заново навбар, а как-то наследовался что-ли от навбара,который я 1 раз уже написал, каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Это не серьезно. Играйтесь с фрагментами и будет все ок.

Comment: Скачайте книгу по андроид разработке, там Вы изучите основу и будете понимать, что к чему. Т.к., к примеру, `NavBar` должен работать с фрагментами, а не активностями.  Ну и в общем, она Вам сильно поможет, куда больше, чем искать какую-то конкретную реализацию какой-то штуки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ранних версиях Android для навигации и быстрого доступа к основным функция использовался элемент ActionBar. Теперь же его функцию выполняет Toolbar.

Это именно то, что в веб-разработке называют NavBar.

Для решения задачи с использованием наследования Toolbar необходимо сделать три шага:

- Создать некую базовую активность, которая работает с тулбаром.
  Прописать все необходимые методы, которые понадобятся для работы
  (например, установка текста в заголовок, включение выключение кнопок,
  обработчик для кнопки назад).
- Наследовать все свои последующие активности от базовой.
- Не забывать добавлять через include общий элемент тулбара.

Вот рабочий пример приложения:

// файл toolbar.xml - вёрстка, описывающая только сам тулбар

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

// ToolbarActivity - активность, реализующая общие для всех активностей методы. Она будет ожидать наличия тулбара в вёрстке, чтобы установить ему тайтл и стрелку назад. При нажатии назад будет срабатывать обычный onBackPressed

```
public abstract class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView toolbarTitle;

    @LayoutRes
    protected abstract int obtainResLayoutId();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(obtainResLayoutId());
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        super.setTitle(title);
        if (toolbarTitle != null)
            toolbarTitle.setText(title);
    }

    protected void enableBackArrow() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
    }

    protected void disableBackArrow() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public final void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

// файл main_activity.xml - вёрстка для основной активити. Через include вставляем тулбар

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE       -->

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

// файл MainActivity - активити-наследница ToolbarActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ToolbarActivity {

    @Override
    protected int obtainResLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.main_activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        enableBackArrow(); // включаем стрелку назад
        setTitle("Main Activity"); // устанавливаем заголовок
    }
}
```

Вот и всё. Удачной разработки!